# How can I get different colors in each element of double loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, loops

This is my code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,positioning,quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4, % Lattice Fundamental domaine q=2
  extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1},
  extended line/.default=1cm]


   \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
   \coordinate (B) at (0:3); %Omega_1
   \coordinate (D) at (60:3); %Omega_2
   \coordinate (C) at ($(B) +(D)$);
   \coordinate (F) at (30:{3/sqrt(3)});
   \coordinate (F') at ($(C) - (F)$);

  \clip ($-1.5*(D)-1.5*(B)$) rectangle ($2.5*(B)+2.5*(D)$);


%Draw lattice lines
\foreach \a in {-1,0,...,2.1}{
\foreach \b in {-1,0,...,2.1}{

\draw[gray,extended line=0.5cm] ($\b*(D)-(B)$) -- ($\b*(D)+2*(B)$);
\draw[gray,extended line=0.5cm] ($\a*(B)-(D)$) -- ($\a*(B)+2*(D)$); }}



%Drow lattice points
\foreach \a in {-1,0,...,2.1}{
\foreach \b in {-1,0,...,2.1}{

\filldraw[] ($\a*(B) + \b*(D)$) circle(2pt);}}


%\filldraw[red] (F) circle(2pt);
%\filldraw[green] (F') circle(2pt);




% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %first rose

\foreach \a/\colora in {-1/{violet!30},0/{violet!50},1/{violet!70},2/{violet!90}}{
\foreach \b in {-2,-1,0,1,2}{
\begin{scope}[shift={($\a*(0:3) + \b*(60:3)$)}]


\filldraw[gray,dashed,fill=\colora,opacity=0.2] (30:{3/sqrt(3)}) -- (0:3) -- ($(0:3) + (60:3) - (30:{3/sqrt(3)})$) -- (60:3) -- cycle ; 


\filldraw[rotate around={120:(60:3)},gray,dashed,fill=\colora,opacity=0.2] (30:{3/sqrt(3)}) -- (0:3) -- ($(0:3) + (60:3) - (30:{3/sqrt(3)})$) -- (60:3) -- cycle ; 

\filldraw[rotate around={240:(60:3)},gray,dashed,fill=\colora,opacity=0.2] (30:{3/sqrt(3)}) -- (0:3) -- ($(0:3) + (60:3) - (30:{3/sqrt(3)})$) -- (60:3) -- cycle ; 
\end{scope}
}}

%Fudamental domaine
\filldraw[gray,dashed,fill=yellow!40!white] (30:{3/sqrt(3)}) -- (0:3) -- ($(0:3) + (60:3) - (30:{3/sqrt(3)})$) -- (60:3) -- cycle ; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

this is how it looks :
[image]

I have a double looping for the scope environment and I want to get a different color for each iteration. I tried to add another loop variable (`\colora`) in the first loop, but I can't go further. I think I can solve my problem if I know a way to mix 2 colors to generate a new color in a syntax allowed by tikz, I will add `\colorb` in the second loop and mix the two colors in each iteration.

---

**Update**

After trying the way given by Gonzalo Medina, I didn't get what I want exactly. It is my fault not explaining the final goal, So I will try to correct that :

In euclidean geometry :  The yellow parallelogram, In the figure above, is what we call fundamental domain (for the action composed by rotation of the angle 0°,120°,240° and translation by Z ω1+ Z ω2, ω1 and ω2 are the generators of the lattice )

Now, If we take a fundamental domain and apply the rotation action only we get
[image]
(I almost just removed the loops)

After that my Idea was to add the action of translation by adding `shift={($\a*(0:3) + \b*(60:3)$)}`, theoretically the result will be a covering of all the plan without any overlaying or intersection.

I want to make clear to the reader the procedure of covering the plan this is why I try to have each translation of the red part in the last picture with a different color.

I am not sure if this is a candidate for a separate question or not, but after Explaining that, I will be happy to have comments about my codes and ways to optimize it because It's the first week since I start coding with tikz, and I am full of doubts about may choices and way of doing things.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Update

I simplified the code using a `\pic` for the fundamental domain. For the color, I present three options:

1. Randomly selecting shades of a fixed color (red, in my example), gives different coloring for each piece:

   ```
   \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
   \usetikzlibrary{calc}

   \tikzset{
      fundamental/.pic={
          \draw[,scale=0.4,black,fill=red!\tmp,rotate around=#1] 
         (60:3) -- ($(0:3) + (60:3) - (30:{3/sqrt(3)})$) -- (0:3) -- (30:{3/sqrt(3)}) -- (60:3);
     }
   }

   \begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4, % Lattice Fundamental domaine q=2
     extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1},
     extended line/.default=1cm]
   \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
   \coordinate (B) at (0:3); %Omega_1
   \coordinate (D) at (60:3); %Omega_2
   \coordinate (C) at ($(B) +(D)$);
   \coordinate (F) at (30:{3/sqrt(3)});
   \coordinate (F') at ($(C) - (F)$);

   \clip ($-1.5*(D)-1.5*(B)$) rectangle ($2.5*(B)+2.5*(D)$);

   \foreach \a in {-1,0,1,2}
   {
     \foreach \b in {-2,-1,0,1}
     {
       \begin{scope}    
       \pgfmathparse{95*rnd+5}
       \edef\tmp{\pgfmathresult}
       \pic at ($ \a*(B) + \b*(D)$ ) {fundamental={240:(60:3)}}; 
       \pic at ($ \a*(B) + \b*(D)$ ) {fundamental={120:(60:3)}}; 
       \pic at ($ \a*(B) + \b*(D)$ ) {fundamental={0:(60:3)}}; 
       \end{scope}
     }
   }

   %Draw lattice lines
   \foreach \a in {-1,0,...,2.1}{
   \foreach \b in {-1,0,...,2.1}{

   \draw[gray,extended line=0.5cm] ($\b*(D)-(B)$) -- ($\b*(D)+2*(B)$);
   \draw[gray,extended line=0.5cm] ($\a*(B)-(D)$) -- ($\a*(B)+2*(D)$); }}

   %Drow lattice points
   \foreach \a in {-1,0,...,2.1}
   {
     \foreach \b in {-1,0,...,2.1}
     {
         \filldraw[] ($\a*(B) + \b*(D)$) circle(2pt);
     }
   }
   \end{tikzpicture}

   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]
2. Randomly selecting different colors for each piece:

   ```
   \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
   \usetikzlibrary{calc}

   \tikzset{
      fundamental/.pic={
          \draw[,scale=0.4,black,fill=MyColor!85,opacity=\opac,rotate around=#1] 
         (60:3) -- ($(0:3) + (60:3) - (30:{3/sqrt(3)})$) -- (0:3) -- (30:{3/sqrt(3)}) -- (60:3);
     }
   }

   \begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4, % Lattice Fundamental domaine q=2
     extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1},
     extended line/.default=1cm]
   \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
   \coordinate (B) at (0:3); %Omega_1
   \coordinate (D) at (60:3); %Omega_2
   \coordinate (C) at ($(B) +(D)$);
   \coordinate (F) at (30:{3/sqrt(3)});
   \coordinate (F') at ($(C) - (F)$);

   \clip ($-1.5*(D)-1.5*(B)$) rectangle ($2.5*(B)+2.5*(D)$);

   \foreach \a in {-1,0,1,2}
   {
     \foreach \b in {-2,-1,0,1}
     {
       \begin{scope}
       \pgfmathparse{250*rnd+5}
       \edef\tmpi{\pgfmathresult}
       \pgfmathparse{210*rnd+45}
       \edef\tmpii{\pgfmathresult}
       \pgfmathparse{230*rnd+25}
       \edef\tmpiii{\pgfmathresult}
       \pgfmathparse{0.75*rnd+0.25}
       \edef\opac{\pgfmathresult}
       \definecolor{MyColor}{RGB}{\tmpi,\tmpii,\tmpiii}    
       \pic at ($ \a*(B) + \b*(D)$ ) {fundamental={240:(60:3)}}; 
       \pic at ($ \a*(B) + \b*(D)$ ) {fundamental={120:(60:3)}}; 
       \pic at ($ \a*(B) + \b*(D)$ ) {fundamental={0:(60:3)}}; 
       \end{scope}
     }
   }

   %Draw lattice lines
   \foreach \a in {-1,0,...,2.1}{
   \foreach \b in {-1,0,...,2.1}{

   \draw[gray,extended line=0.5cm] ($\b*(D)-(B)$) -- ($\b*(D)+2*(B)$);
   \draw[gray,extended line=0.5cm] ($\a*(B)-(D)$) -- ($\a*(B)+2*(D)$); }}

   %Drow lattice points
   \foreach \a in {-1,0,...,2.1}
   {
     \foreach \b in {-1,0,...,2.1}
     {
         \filldraw[] ($\a*(B) + \b*(D)$) circle(2pt);
     }
   }
   \end{tikzpicture}

   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]
3. Using fixed colors for each "row":

   ```
   \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
   \usetikzlibrary{calc}

   \tikzset{
      fundamental/.pic={
          \draw[,scale=0.4,black,fill=\colora!80!\colorb,opacity=0.7,rotate around=#1] 
         (60:3) -- ($(0:3) + (60:3) - (30:{3/sqrt(3)})$) -- (0:3) -- (30:{3/sqrt(3)}) -- (60:3);
     }
   }

   \begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4, % Lattice Fundamental domaine q=2
     extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1},
     extended line/.default=1cm]
   \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
   \coordinate (B) at (0:3); %Omega_1
   \coordinate (D) at (60:3); %Omega_2
   \coordinate (C) at ($(B) +(D)$);
   \coordinate (F) at (30:{3/sqrt(3)});
   \coordinate (F') at ($(C) - (F)$);

   \clip ($-1.5*(D)-1.5*(B)$) rectangle ($2.5*(B)+2.5*(D)$);

   \foreach \a/\colora in {-1/red,0/green,1/blue,2/purple}
   {
     \foreach \b/\colorb in {-2/yellow,-1/magenta,0/gray,1/orange}
     {
       \begin{scope}
       \pic at ($ \a*(B) + \b*(D)$ ) {fundamental={240:(60:3)}}; 
       \pic at ($ \a*(B) + \b*(D)$ ) {fundamental={120:(60:3)}}; 
       \pic at ($ \a*(B) + \b*(D)$ ) {fundamental={0:(60:3)}}; 
       \end{scope}
     }
   }

   %Draw lattice lines
   \foreach \a in {-1,0,...,2.1}{
   \foreach \b in {-1,0,...,2.1}{

   \draw[gray,extended line=0.5cm] ($\b*(D)-(B)$) -- ($\b*(D)+2*(B)$);
   \draw[gray,extended line=0.5cm] ($\a*(B)-(D)$) -- ($\a*(B)+2*(D)$); }}

   %Drow lattice points
   \foreach \a in {-1,0,...,2.1}
   {
     \foreach \b in {-1,0,...,2.1}
     {
         \filldraw[] ($\a*(B) + \b*(D)$) circle(2pt);
     }
   }
   \end{tikzpicture}

   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]

Comment: thank you very much. the truth is that this not the final result I wanted, so please read my Update, I have added further explanation.

Comment: @AymaneFihadi Please see my updated answer. Is it something like that what you had in mind?

Comment: This is perfectly what I had in mind, thank you for all your help.  This is the first time I see `\pgfmathparse` `\pgfmathresult` they are very helpful. what I didn't understand is the `rnd` without backslash it seems for me like a normal text, but from the context I can see that it return a number between 0 and 1, is that true, and what it is exactly if isn't a macro.

Comment: @AymaneFihadi You're welcome. `rnd` generates a pseudo-random number between 0 and 1. It is part of the PGF math engine; using this engine you can perform many mathematical operations. All available functions and operators are described in Section **89
Mathematical Expressions** of the PGF manual for version 3.0.